# 2.10 - iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution, my app should only run on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I submitted an app and it got rejected because of that Error. It is an iPhone App only, why should it be able to run on an iPad?

2.10 Details

We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.4.1, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Is it not possible to make an App only for iPhone and not for iPad aswell?

Comment: I don't think anyone here can tell you that the guidelines are lies.  But if you have specific features that your app needs, look at the required device capabilities section of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: Okay, so I will just try to fix it . Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop an iPhone-only app and it can get approved.  However, iPad devices can download iPhone-only apps and use them.  They run at iPhone size with lots of black space around the display.  Users have the option of tapping a button in the corner to double the size so that it fills more of the screen.

I assume that they ran your iPhone-only app on an iPad and encountered errors. It doesn't have to have an iPad layout, but it should be able to run on an iPad. When they first released the iPad, most (all?) apps worked without modification in this mode on iPad.

Here is an example of what another app looks like running on an iPad: [image](http://gagengirls.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/2013-07-06-19.05.12.png).